# A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause.?

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities, entities

```
var query1 = datatable1.AsEnumerable().Select(a => a.["StudentID"]).ToList();
var query2 = datatable2.AsEnumerable().Select(b =>b.["StudentID"]).ToList();

var exceptAB=query1.Except(query2);

DataTable Match = (from a in datatable1.AsEnumerable()
                   join ab in exceptAB on a["StudentID"].ToString() equals 
                   ab.StudentID select a).CopyToDataTable();
```

**ToList();** error in fields.

This error A query body must end with a select  clause or a group clause.

and then

**a => a.["StudentID"])**

**b => b.["StudentID"])**

this error is Identifier expected.

Comment: What do you think `.[` would be? Where did you get that syntax?

Comment: Hi.Get the value of id from table 1 with linq.Take the value of ID in the same way from the 2nd table and to ensure that these values are equal.But I need to do this with linq. When I searched, I saw that I could do it in this way.

Comment: That is not valid C# or LINQ. Where did you see this syntax?

Comment: I can't find it right now.It was a code I tried in many researches.Maybe it was () syntax.I tried that way(a=>a.StudentID) but take error.Well if this is wrong in case id id how do i get another with linq.

Comment: In C#, data types are your friend - what is the type of `a`? After `AsEnumerable`, you have `IEnumerable<DataRow>` and so the type of `a` is `DataRow`. How do you access fields? You can use indexing with column names or numbers or the `Field<>` method: `a["StudentID"]` or `a.Field<int>("StudentID")`. If you use indexing the return type is `object`, so you typically want to cast to the correct type: `(int)a["StudentID"]`.